# Spring Boot Open API 3.0 - How to show custom examples without writing a Json Manually

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, openapi

I am working in a Spring Boot 2.5.2 + Java 8 project which has Open API 3.0:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.14</version>
</dependency>
```

I need to show some specific error bodies to the user like this:

This example comes from **another** Spring boot project where swagger is mapped with an yaml file.
[image]

---

---

---

I need to show examples with a similar body but using annotations (because if a new endpoint is added it will be automatically mapped to the Swagger UI. We are facing an issue where developers are forgetting to map the endpoint in the yaml file, this action is trying to avoid this).

Here are my mapping:

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "401",
                    description = "Something is required.",
                    content = {
                            @Content(mediaType = "application/json",

                                    examples = {

                                        //The problem lays here!!
                                    }

                            )

                    })
    })
    public abstract ResponseEntity<Mono<Object>> queryLegacy(String query);
```

My error class is `ErpResponseBodyDTO.class`.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ErpResponseBodyDTO{
  private Long code;
  private String message;
}
```

How can I create a Instance of this class like `new ErpResponseBodyDTO(123, "Error Message");` and use this instance as an Example?

I mean, something like:

```
...
@Content(mediaType = "application/json",

examples = {

    new ErpResponseBodyDTO(123, "Error Message"),
    new ErpResponseBodyDTO(456, "Error Message 2"),
    new ErpResponseBodyDTO(789, "Error Message 3")
}
)
...
```

I don't want to write manually a Json Example because my API has a lot of possible errors and writing it in the `@ExampleObject(value="  {"A":"BIG", "JSON":"HERE"}  ")` will pollute the code.

Comment: So you mean you need it only in the swagger documentation?

Comment: @Jens exactly, only in Swagger. I need to create custom Examples, like in the print that is on my question but only in Swagger.

Comment: *my API has a lot of possible errors* But it is an example, so one should be enough?

Comment: @Jens hmm, not exaclty a simple example. There's a requirement in which I need to show the possible errors that might occur. This is a requirement because the company has a service desk, and they would like to take look at the error our users are saying that are facing. So, for example, if there's a 409 http code and there's 3 possible ways this 409 is thrown I need to map theses 3 possible ways in swagger UI.

Comment: You can use @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successfully retrieved list") to your controller for describing

Comment: @Yeras_QazaQ I need to show examples. This suggestion only documents the http status and the description of it. I need to do something like in the print, but less verbose than writing all the possible responses hard coded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**

*Solution: Document the API programmatically.*

Spring has a lib that you can manipulate the entire OpenAPI project.

There's my configuration class, which is the solution:

```java
package br.orchestratorapi.config;

import br.com.dto.ErpResponseBodyDTO;
import br.com.exception.MessageError;
import br.com.exception.MyExceptionWrapperClassException;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.examples.Example;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.media.MediaType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.responses.ApiResponse;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.io.UncheckedIOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Optional;

@Configuration
public class OpenAPIExamples {

@Value("classpath:/swagger_examples.json")
    private Resource swaggerExamples;

    @Bean
    public OpenApiCustomiser openApiCustomiser() {
        return openAPI -> buildExamplesFromJson().forEach(exampleValue -> setExamplesOnEndpoints(openAPI, exampleValue, "application/json"));
    }

    private void setExamplesOnEndpoints(OpenAPI api, ExampleValue exampleValue, String bodyType) {
        Optional.ofNullable(api.getPaths())
                .map(paths -> paths.get(exampleValue.getPath()))
                .map(paths -> getOperationForHttpMethod(exampleValue.getHttpMethod(), paths))
                .ifPresent(operation -> setExamplesOnEndpoints(exampleValue, bodyType, operation));
    }

    private void setExamplesOnEndpoints(ExampleValue exampleValue, String bodyType, Operation operation) {
        ApiResponse response = operation.getResponses().get(String.valueOf(exampleValue.getHttpStatus()));
        if(response == null)
             response = new ApiResponse();

        Content content = response.getContent();
        if(content == null)
             content = new Content();

        MediaType mediaType = content.get(bodyType);

        if(mediaType == null)
            mediaType = new MediaType();

        mediaType.addExamples(exampleValue.getExampleName(), exampleValue.getExample());

        content.put(bodyType, mediaType);
        response.setContent(content);

        operation.getResponses().put(String.valueOf(exampleValue.getHttpStatus()), response);
    }


    private Operation getOperationForHttpMethod(String httpMethod, PathItem paths) {
        switch (httpMethod) {
            case "POST":
                return paths.getPost();
            case "PATCH":
                return paths.getPatch();
            case "PUT":
                return paths.getPut();
            case "DELETE":
                return paths.getDelete();
            case "GET":
                return paths.getGet();
            case "OPTIONS":
                return paths.getOptions();
            case "HEAD":
                return paths.getHead();
            case "TRACE":
                return paths.getTrace();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    public List<ExampleValue> buildExamplesFromJson() {
        List<ExampleValue> result = new ArrayList<>();

        JsonObject jsonObject = new Gson().fromJson(asString(swaggerExamples), JsonObject.class);
        JsonArray endpoints = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("endpoints");

        endpoints.forEach(element -> {
            JsonObject path = element.getAsJsonObject();

            String endpointPath = path.get("path").getAsString();
            String method = path.get("method").getAsString();

            path.get("responses").getAsJsonArray().forEach(response -> {
                JsonObject resp = response.getAsJsonObject();

                int status = resp.get("status").getAsInt();

                resp.getAsJsonArray("errors").forEach(error -> {

                    JsonObject errorObj = error.getAsJsonObject();
                    String enumName = errorObj.get("enum").getAsString();


                    Example example = new Example();
                    example.description(errorObj.get("description").getAsString());
                    example.value(ErpResponseBodyDTO.builder().error(new MyExceptionWrapperClassException(MessageError.valueOf(enumName)).getResponse().getError()).build());

                    ExampleValue exampleValue = new ExampleValue(errorObj.get("exampleName").getAsString(), example, status, method, endpointPath);

                    result.add(exampleValue);

                });

            });


        });

        return result;

    }

    public static String asString(Resource resource) {
        try (Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream())) {
            return FileCopyUtils.copyToString(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    private class ExampleValue {
        private String exampleName;
        private Example example;
        private int httpStatus;
        private String httpMethod;
        private String path;
    }

 }
```

As you can see, I read a Json file from resources:

```
{
  "endpoints": [


    {
      "path":  "/endpoint/that/{already}/{exists-in-swagger}",
      "method": "POST",
      "responses": [

        {
          "status":  401,
          "errors":[
            {"description":"A description","enum": "ENUM_THAT_I_HAVE_SO_PAY_ATTENTION", "exampleName":  "You have thrown an error"}
          ]
        }

      ]
    }


  ]
}
```